# Angular Child Scope value doesn't bind correctly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm writing an angular app where I need to bind values to some child scope.
In the controller, I have:

```js
var addToStack = function(fallingItemOrder, scope) {
  scope.model.stageChimneys[fallingItemOrder].Stack += 1;
  return (scope.model.stageChimneys[fallingItemOrder].Stack === 3);
};
```

Where `scope` is referenced to `$scope` with `$id=2` (I guess it's 2 because it lives under an `ng-view` directive.)

The main view has this code:

```
<ul class="chimneysUL">
  <li ng-repeat="chimney in model.stageChimneys" ng-include="model.chimneyUrl"></li>
</ul>
```

And the `ng-include` fetches this sub-view, which is rendered 5 times with different data:

```html
<div class="chimney" id="{{chimney.LetterCode}}" data-order="{{$parent.$index}}">
  <div class="pipeHead"></div>
  <div class="pipeBody">
    <table class="ulInsertedLetters">
      <tr ng-repeat="i in model.getNumber(model.stackSize) track by $index" ng-class="3 - $index <= chimney.Stack ? 'showInserted' : 'hideInserted'">
        <td>
          <img class="insertedLetterImg" data-ng-src="{{'../../Images/Cards/rectangle.jpg'}}" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="picContainer">
    <img class="card" data-ng-src="{{chimney.PicName}}" />
  </div>
</div>
```

All bindings seem to be correct (e.g. chimney.LetterCode etc..)
but when addToStack executes, the `{{chimney.Stack}}` remains unchanged.

As I understand scopes, if the parent scope with `$id = 2` has it's model properties change, then those changes should permeate down and reflect instantaneously in the html view.

And indeed in debugging, I can see that diving into `$$childTail --> $$prevSibling`, the chimney object has it's Stack property incremented.

So what's the missing part I've overlooked?

Comment: Where do you expect the change to happen ? ng-class ?

Comment: Suggest you create a demo that replicates problem. We can't see where `addtoStack` is even being used

Comment: each <tr> should have a `showInserted` or `hideInserted` depending on the calculation in ng-class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an issue in conception. Whatever's inside your included template shouldn't try and access what's outside. You should use a directive instead.

I'm not 100% sure, but I think that ng-include creates another scope. So whatever modification that happens in your main view is not reported to your included template because the value in that new scope wasn't changed.

Edit:

If you call your function from outside a digest (for instance in a callback passed to a 3rd-party library, on in a setTimeout function), the view will not be updated, because angular has no way of knowing a value has changed.. In that case, you have to surround your call with a $scope.$apply() call.

Comment: Is there a built-in directive for such interactions? I find it odd that such a barrier was placed between the main view and it's included templates in angular. guess it's engineered like this for a good reason...

Comment: Well, i makes sense that a template should be self-contained. Why would a template be aware of whatever template is including it? You should pass arguments to that template, and the only way to do that is to transform that template into a directive, which is not as hard as it seems.

Comment: @yaronhochman Actually, the included template is aware of the outer scope. You don't have to change to directive.

Comment: Also, there's nothing wrong with including templates in the main view, as long as they're not sharing variables. I made that mistake in my early angular days, and now I'm refactoring my code using directives. And keep in mind that pure controllers are gonna disappear in angular 2.0 and everything is basically gonna be directives. Might as well start coding that way now :)

Comment: That being said, @omri-aharon is right, you should be able to access chimney.Stack and watch its changes inside your template...

Comment: Maybe there's a digest issue. How is addToStack called? What I usually do when I suspect a digest issue is execute this in the console: angular.element(document.body).injector().get('$rootScope').$digest(). If you view updates, then you forgot to trigger a digest somewhere.

Comment: addToStack is a function within the controller. but why should it matter if it works against a `scope` var referencing the rootScope? btw, if i set Stack to 1 at the init stage, it's permeating to the template. it's from the addToStack function that it fails to work.

Comment: It does matter. If you call your function from outside a digest (for instance in a callback passed to a 3rd-party library, on in a setTimeout function), the view will not be updated, because angular has no way of knowing a value has changed.. In that case, you have to surround your call with a $scope.$apply() call.

Comment: Problem solved. indeed it had to do with running the watcher manually inside the function. thanks jlowcs for the clarification.

Comment: Good :) I still think a directive would be better :)